# adding text using ajax call from json string

Tags: html, ajax, json, dom

I'm a bit new to ajax and my javascript isn't to shabby I'm having a difficult time figuring this out. I'm trying to add values from a JSON string located on a separate url to my html code through an AJAX Get method.

Currently this is my code:

```
$.ajax({
dataType: "jsonp",
jsonp: 'callback',
cache: false,

url: "http://www.url.com/userInfo/currentUserInfo",
success: function(data) {
    $("#name").val("firstName");
    $("#avatar").val("userProfileImg");
    $("#notNum").val("numOfNotifications");
}
});
```

Html

```
 <div id="name"></div>
 <div id="avatar"></div>
 <div id="notNum"></div>
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something in the ajax script.. but to be honest I can't figure out what. Could someone lend a helping hand?

Thanks!

Comment: is there any error in the console? also are you sure the server is supporting `jsonp`

Comment: is the success handler fired, or is there a problem elsewhere?

Comment: Open up network tab in your chrome console and see if your request is going through or getting CORS related error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use data that the end point is returning in the success function.  As you've written it, the contents of the element will be replaced with the strings "firstName", "userProfileImg", "numOfNotifications" which probably isn't your intent.

Also, you will need to use the `text()` function to add text to a div.  If your service is returning HTML, then use the `html()` function instead.

```
$.ajax({
dataType: "jsonp",
jsonp: 'callback',
cache: false,

url: "http://www.url.com/userInfo/currentUserInfo",
success: function(data) {
    // use html() if any of the data fields contain markup
    $("#name").text(data.firstName); markup
    $("#avatar").text(data.userProfileImg);
    $("#notNum").text(data.numOfNotifications);
}
});
```

Comment: Sweet thanks Jason. have are looking on the brighter side now. I am still getting an error though and I'm not sure whether it has to do with the ajax call or the Json string. I'm getting an error in my console that says: "Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token: and it is pointing to the url of the Json string. 

Does this mean that there is something wrong with the Json string? or is there something still wrong w/ my ajax script. By the way thanks again for the help

Answer (score 2):

`val()` is for input. So you can use `.html()` or `.text()` for the div element here.

If your ajax call reaches success handler this should give your intended result.

```
    $("#name").html("firstName"); // or data["firstName"] ?
    $("#avatar").html("userProfileImg"); //or data["userProfileImg"]
    $("#notNum").html("numOfNotifications"); //or data["numOfNotifications"]
```

[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 0):

1000's of data u can do in single line.

use this.
keep your json data as

```
{"name":"raja","age":20,"register_no":"19283KSR"}
```

keep your component id names like

1.cmp_name
2.cmp_age
3.cmp_register_no

do this in your ajax success

```
for (var index in data){
if ($("#cmp_"+index).length != 0) 
    $("#cmp_"+index).html(data[index]);
}
```

To validate your json see [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)